# How to increase the distance between boxplots (ggplot2) which have discrete x-axis - position_dodge?

Tags: r, ggplot2, distance, boxplot

I am trying to change the distance between boxplots in a ggplot2 figure. I have boxplots which show the data for different categories of products.
The categories (x-axis) are discrete variables.
I tried position_dodge which did not affect the distance between the boxplots. It worked when the x-axis was a continuous variable.

Which command would increase the distance between the boxplots when x-axis is discrete?

```
require(ggplot2)
dat<-rbind(data.frame(approach=1,product=1,value=seq(1,20,0.5)),
  data.frame(approach=1,product=2,value=seq(5,15,0.3)),
  data.frame(approach=1,product=3,value=seq(5,17,0.2)),
  data.frame(approach=2,product=1,value=seq(1,13,0.3)),
  data.frame(approach=2,product=2,value=seq(3,18,0.5)),
  data.frame(approach=2,product=3,value=seq(4,25,0.7)),
  data.frame(approach=3,product=1,value=seq(1,15,0.6)),
  data.frame(approach=3,product=2,value=seq(3,16,0.5)),
  data.frame(approach=3,product=3,value=seq(1,10,0.1)))
dat$product<-as.factor(dat$product)

gg1<-ggplot(dat,aes(x =product, y = value, width = 4)) +
     geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(1))
gg1
```

[image]

Comment: Dodging is for when you have multiple objects at the *same* position, such as 2 sets of boxplots with different colors based on some group. It doesn't apply here since that's not the case. You can just set a `width = ..` argument in your `geom_boxplot`, something like 0.4 works nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely clear but...Do you want to play with `width` ?

`geom_boxplot(width=0.5)` produces

[image]

`geom_boxplot(width=0.1)` produces

[image]